# Gitlab doesn't allow me to force push into remote repo since the branch is protected. What alternative other than force push can I do?

Tags: gitlab

I pushed something by mistake into the remote repo.
Now I wanted to go back one commit and then force push it, to correct the remote repo.

```
>>git reset HEAD~
>>git push -f
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push
```

Instead of removing the protection in Gitlab and try to force push again, it seems
too risky since it's a big project.
What is another alternative that I can use to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: If it's something sensitive like a password or a token, ask the repository owner for help. The owner can force-push or un-protect the branch. If it's not sensitive, you could revert the commit and create a merge request to update the branch.

Answer (score 4):

[No one can force push to a protected branch on Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html). You have to [allow force pushes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#allow-force-push-on-a-protected-branch), force push, and then disallow again.

Risk is minimal. Since the branch remains protected, only people who can push can force push. Presumably they are trusted.

Even if someone force pushes in that brief window, you still have your own local copy and can fix the remote repository.

Finally, don't use --force. [Use --force-with-lease](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/). This ensures you don't overwrite other people's work. I like to alias this as `git repush`.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern , I'll keep this in mind as my first option but what are other alternatives that I can use instead of force push to get the same results? I want to have other options to consider too

Comment: @tadm123 If you want to wipe history, force push is your only option. Consider how that mistake got past your review process.